# Java.- Ignorando los últimos elementos de un array

Tags: java, array

Necesito ayuda para resolver este ejercicio pero no soy bueno para los arrays y realmente no tengo idea de como realizar este programa.

Entrada

```
5
7 4 1 8 9
2
```

Salida

```
7 4 1
```

Lo que entendi fue que tengo que llenar un array desde teclado (7 4 1 8 9) y despues colocar la cantidad de numeros a ignorar(2)

*El ejercico dice lo siguiente:*

> **Entrada:** Un entero N seguido de los N enteros del array y después un entero K.
> **Salida:** Los enteros del array ignorando sus últimos K elementos.

Este es el codigo que hice pero la plataforma en la que estoy me lo pone como mal y segun yo esta bien:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int [] numeros=new int[n];
    
        for (int i=0; i<(n); i++){
            numeros[i]=sc.nextInt();   
        }
        int k=sc.nextInt();
        for (int i=0; i<(n-k); i++){
            System.out.print(numeros[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Si añades el código con lo que hayas intentado podremos ayudarte. Lo que te pide es que "juegues" con las posiciones del array, y ten en cuenta que el primer elemento es el 0.

Comment: ya lo actualize, y la verdad me confundo mucho cuando se trata de arreglos o matrices

Comment: Te falta el espacio entre cada número, ese código muestra `741` en lugar de `7 4 1`. Lo puedes comprobar [aquí](https://tio.run/##bZBPT4NAEMXvfIo5QpoSNRo1yMXEQw/GxHojHFZY6vBnluwObdXw2XEJ2NKWuWwy7@37vd1cbMUyT4uuw6pWmiG3Cx@V/9xkmdQyfZcilTpwzuTV28s@kTWjokuN6obXrKWo5m43jKVvZaTNhyok4c@8IxFEveLUzWeJCSSlMAZeBRL8OmBn3BsWbI@twhQqq7pDdhSD0BvjAX9ptTMwaTze72ekgEkgBJK7/4W7/jYsKx/JCw5mJAayPpP4JPe8InbPVAulppJambAPs6uI4sFy8GVKg9ubMbwKAJ9ciwBcLLxjq37GnAjj8IQ3jWpP4EU4X@wSuCxmkeObVcN@bb@Q3WOHSdwAbZ226@6ce7iFa3iAR@fmDw)